# Convert saturate_cast<uchar> in c++ to Java

Tags: java, c++, opencv

I would like to know how to convert the following C++ code into java. 
In particular, I need to convert RGB images into Opponent Space Images in order to extract the features for matching in my AR application.

```
void rgb2OpponentColorspace(Mat &bgrImage, vector<Mat> &opponentImageChannels)
{
          if(bgrImage.type() != CV_8UC3)
          {
                       cerr << "Error, attempting to convert to opponent space a non-BGR image!\n";
                       return;
          }
          //opponentImageChannels.resize(3);
          opponentImageChannels.push_back(Mat(bgrImage.size(),CV_8UC1));
          opponentImageChannels.push_back(Mat(bgrImage.size(),CV_8UC1));
          opponentImageChannels.push_back(Mat(bgrImage.size(),CV_8UC1));

          for(int y = 0; y < bgrImage.rows; ++y)
          {
                 for(int x = 0; x < bgrImage.cols; ++x)
                 {

                       Vec3b v = bgrImage.at<Vec3b>(y, x);
                       uchar& b = v[0];
                       uchar& g = v[1];
                       uchar& r = v[2];

                       opponentImageChannels[0].at<uchar>(y, x) = saturate_cast<uchar>(0.5f    * (255 + g - r));       // (R - G)/sqrt(2), but converted to the destination data type
                       opponentImageChannels[1].at<uchar>(y, x) = saturate_cast<uchar>(0.25f   * (510 + r + g - 2*b)); // (R + G - 2B)/sqrt(6), but converted to the destination data type
                       opponentImageChannels[2].at<uchar>(y, x) = saturate_cast<uchar>(1.f/3.f * (r + g + b));         // (R + G + B)/sqrt(3), but converted to the destination data type

                 }
```

Comment: Id suggest you that instead of trying to strictly convert your code from c++ to java that you try starting it from scratch into java. Also... if you have tried something so far in Java post it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some discussion with my senior and we come out with the following solution.

```
    opponentImageChannels.add(new Mat(mReferenceBGRImage.size(), CvType.CV_32FC1));
    opponentImageChannels.add(new Mat(mReferenceBGRImage.size(), CvType.CV_32FC1));
    opponentImageChannels.add(new Mat(bgrImage.size(), CvType.CV_32FC1));

    for (int y = 0; y < bgrImage.rows(); ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < bgrImage.cols(); ++x) {

            double[] data = bgrImage.get(y, x);

            double b = data[0];
            double g = data[1];
            double r = data[2];

            opponentImageChannels.get(0).put(y, x, 0.5f * (255 + g + r));
            opponentImageChannels.get(1).put(y, x, 0.25 * (510 + r + g - 2 * b));
            opponentImageChannels.get(2).put(y, x, 0.5f * 1.0f / 3.0f * (r + g + b));


             }
```

1) By using .add to replace .pushback
2) By using .get to replace .at
3) By using .put to place something into the channel

Answer (score 0):

You may try implement this function by yourself, like this:

```
private final static int MAX_UCHAR = 255;

public static int saturateCastUchar(int x) {
  return x > MAX_UCHAR ? MAX_UCHAR : (x < 0 ? 0 : x);
}

public static int saturateCastUchar(float x) {
  return (int) (x > MAX_UCHAR ? MAX_UCHAR : (x < 0 ? 0 : x));
}
```

OpenCV for Java doesn't contain any ready-for-use function for this.